# play recorded sound during voice call using NDK or Third Party APIs

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have explored a lot to find out how to play a pre-recorded audio during voice call in android , but everywhere i noticed that its impossible with the currently supported APIs and there isn't any work around too.

so what i want to know is does anyone know how to do it using NDK or any other external APIs ?

i tried to even re-communicate with members who had asked the question , but most of them were seen 1 year back , so i got to ask it again.

> my main point is , if anyone has explored how to implement this  using
>   NDK then please do share the road map to do the same ?

***UPDATE***

I tried playing a recorded file on a speaker phone at the time when other person picks up a call but the audio file play at my end only not on the other person's end even though i have played on my speaker phone.  so this solution doesnt work.